# Changing window.location with relative url using its own context

Tags: javascript, iframe, relative-path

**The problem**

In my application I have a parent page which contains an iframe to a child page in a subdirectory.

> parent.html
>   subdir/child.html

From within the child page, I would like to set the location of the parent page using a relative url ("targetPage.html"), *relative to the parent*.

> parent.html
>   targetPage.html (**correct** target)
>   subdir/child.html (source of action)
>   subdir/targetPage.html (**incorrect**)

From within the child, I can say:

```
window.parent.location = "targetPage.html";
```

...but of course, that (incorrectly) navigates the parent page to "subdir/targetPage.html", because the code is running in the context of the child.

Calling code in the parent doesn't help:

```
window.parent.myFunctionToNavigateToTarget(); // defined in parent to navigate to "targetPage.html"
```

... has the same effect, as the parent's function is being run in the context of the child.

**The Question**

Is there an elegant way to set the location of another window using a relative URL, in such a way that it's interpretted relative to that window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could grab the hostname and path off the parent window and then append your target page:

```
var targetPage = 'somepage.html';

var url = window.parent.location.href;
if(url.indexOf('.') > -1){
   url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
}
window.parent.location = url + targetPage;
```

Comment: you'll get an errror if you try reading indexOf of window.location- use  window.location.href instead

Comment: I get an error: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL parentUrl from frame with URL childUrl Domains, protocols and ports must match.